# How to use sql different where statement on the basis of column's value?

Tags: sql, knex.js

I have table named `offers`.It has following columns

1. `is_special` having value true or false
2. `normal_expiry_date` having a date value
3. `special_expiry_date` having a date value

Now if row has `is_special = false` then I want to use `where normal_expiry_date > current_date`,if
`is_special = true` then `where special_expiry_date > current_date`

Thanks a lot to you even if you tried to help

Comment: Please don't spam the database tags: `mysql` <> `oracle` <> `postgresql`. Which one do you actually use?

Comment: @ShaheryarAhmed . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: From a performance and complexity standpoint, I would strive to avoid such a design, conditionally comparing to one column or the other.  I would much rather compare to a single `expiry_date` column. But if that's not possible, then I would at least avoid an `OR` condition, and compare `current_date` to a single expression e.g. `current_date < CASE WHEN ... THEN t.special_expiry_date WHEN ... THEN t.normal_expiry_date ELSE ... END` , with some some databases, that gives the possibility to create a function based index, as if that expression was a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be

```
where current_date < case when is_special = false then normal_expiry_date
                          when is_special = true  then special_expiry_date
                     end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean logic:

```
where 
    (is_special = 'false' and normal_expiry_date > current_date)
    or (is_special = 'true' and special_expiry_date  > current_date)
```

Note: it is unclear what the datatype of `is_specia` is, so you might need to adapt the equality condition. If that's a Postgres boolean for example:

```
where 
    (not is_special and normal_expiry_date > current_date)
    or (is_special and special_expiry_date  > current_date)
```